# Key-Value Observing NSCache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, key-value-observing, nscache

I want to get notified when the object corresponding to a certain key in an NSCache instance changes. I've tried using Key-Value Observing without luck (the console doesn't log anything).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.cache addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myKey" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [self.cache setObject:@"myObject" forKey:@"myKey"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"KEYPATH CHANGED: %@", keyPath);
}
```

How can I observe the contents of an NSCache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would expect `NSCache` not to be key-value observing (KVO) compliant for that sort of key. KVO is implemented internally at the `NSObject` level by replacing the normal setter with one that alerts relevant observers and calls the original setter. In the case of things you set with `setObject:forKey:` there is no specific setter so nothing for the runtime to hang off.

Since `NSCache` doesn't post any relevant notifications I think your best hope is [the delegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCacheDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCacheDelegate). It's not explicit exactly what counts as an eviction but if `cache:willEvictObject:` is called when the object associated with a key is changed on purpose then you could hook directly off that.

Otherwise I'd recommend you create a wrapper class for `NSCache`, say `DWCache` for argument's sake, that contains an `NSCache`, is the delegate of the cache, and provides its own `setObject:forKey:`. It will posts an appropriate message (i) upon the first call to setObject:forKey:; (ii) upon every subsequent call that supplies an object different from that already in the cache; and (iii) whenever it receives a `cache:willEvictObject:`.

The only potential complexity is that `NSCache` doesn't copy the original keys and, partly as a result, has no means to get key from object. You may want to store those connections separately, e.g. through an `NSDictionary`. Provided you clear the dictionary when the cache evicts the object you'll still be providing caching behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer. I'm using a custom wrapper around NSCache that has an NSCache and NSMutableDictionary property. The wrapper implements custom addObserver and removeObserver KVO methods that are passed to the dictionary and also implements the NSCache delegate to update the contents of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;
```

keyPath is the key that changed, object is the new value.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant with "I've tried using KVO". Edited my question to be more clear.